Undefined variable $slot Error in Laravel Livewire Component When Using Slots
I'm working on a Laravel application using Livewire for dynamic components. I'm trying to pass data to a Livewire component using slots, but I keep encountering an "Undefined variable $slot" error. I've followed the standard documentation for Livewire slots but can't resolve this issue.
Livewire Component View (resources/views/livewire/example-component.blade.php):
<div>
    <h1>Here's the slot content:</h1>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>

Usage in my blade template
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <livewire:example-component>
        <p>test</p>
    </livewire:example-component>
@endsection

Why do i get the "Undefined variable $slot" error when I try to load the page. Does anyone know why Livewire isn't recognizing the slot content, or what else I might check to resolve this issue?

From the documentation, you can use the below. This define a default value if $slot is not defined. You can change this to only include content if $slot is provided.
<span class="alert-title">{{ $title }}</span>
 
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    @if ($slot->isEmpty())
        This is default content if the slot is empty.
    @else
        {{ $slot }}
    @endif
</div>


If clause required even when $slot content is clearly defined... insane!
